# Can a weapon be made of both cold iron and adamantine alloy?

Tags: weapons, starfinder, special-materials

From the SFSRD on [Adamantine](http://www.starfindersrd.com/equipment/weapons/#Adamantine_Alloy) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Adamantine Alloy**
>   Adamantine is a starmetal... Pure adamantine is exceedingly rare and expensive, so *weapons using adamantine are always made of an adamantine alloy*. Weapons or ammunition fashioned from adamantine alloy overcome the damage reduction... Weapons and ammunition without metal parts can’t be made from adamantine alloy.

From the SFSRD on [Cold Iron](http://www.starfindersrd.com/equipment/weapons/#Cold_Iron):

> **Cold Iron**
>   Cold iron is... Weapons or ammunition fashioned from cold iron overcome the damage reduction... Weapons or ammunition without metal parts can’t be made from cold iron.

From the SFSRD on [Silver](http://www.starfindersrd.com/equipment/weapons/#Silver) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Silver**
>   A complex process involving alchemy, magic, and metallurgy can bond silver to weapons or ammunition so that they overcome the damage reduction of... The silvering process can’t be applied to nonmetal items, *and it doesn’t work on rare metals such as adamantine, cold iron, or starmetals*.

Silver weapons explicitly cannot also be adamantine, cold iron, or other starmetal-based special materials. Adamantine and cold iron do not spell out similar restrictions, and adamantine even explicitly says the weapon is made of an alloy that simply *includes* adamantine.

Can a weapon be made of an alloy of adamantine and cold iron and gain both benefits?

Comment: Assuming that neither version is explicit about it, this 3.5 edition question might be a possible duplicate: [How many special materials can one weapon be made from?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/85213)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No

From page 191 of the *Starfinder Core Rulebook:*

> If you make a weapon out of more than one special material, you get the benefit of only the most prevalent material.

You could alloy them together, but in the end, only one will apply.